# New LCD screen with random black screen

Tags: monitor

I bought a new LCD screen and now my computer's screen goes black for 1 second randomly. I am using dual boot and windows 8.1 works without any error, also my old LCD screen didn't have any kind of this problem. I have tried another new LCD screen and it had the same issue. Should I renew driver or something? I have tried changing refresh rate, it helped for sometime but had the same problem after that.

Comment: You should adjust for the new native resolution and refresh rate if different, that's all.

Comment: It has the same resolution, so I am using old configuration.

Comment: If you are using HDMI cable, consider replacing that cable.

Comment: I have a laptop and I am not using HDMI cable.